# "no implicit conversion of Integer into String" error with Jekyll posts that have numbered titles

Tags: github, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I have [a Jekyll blog](https://keywords.oxus.net/) hosted [on GitHub Pages that](https://github.com/kerim/keywords) I recently updated to HTTPS. In doing so, I discovered that recent updates to Jekyll were causing my blog to no longer build properly. Running a local install I kept encountering the following error:

```
Liquid Exception: no implicit conversion of Integer into String in /_layouts/default.html
```

After some trial and error I was able to identify the following posts as causing the problem:

```
2003-09-21-100.md
2004-02-10-10000.md
2004-02-28-228.md
2004-09-10-1.md
2004-10-10-1969.md
2004-11-06-1896.md
2005-05-14-616.md
```

These are all old Wordpress posts that I imported into Jekyll, and as you can see, they all have numbers as titles. It didn't cause build problems on earlier versions of Jekyll however. While I could rename all of these old posts, it would be a bit of a pain since I would have to update any Disqus comments URLs, and any existing links on the web to those posts would be broken. Does anyone know if there is an easier way to fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The real problem is that the `escape` filter isn't able to handle numbers, for example:

```
{{ 1618 | escape }}
```

Throws:

```
/tmp/vendor/ruby/2.3.0/gems/liquid-4.0.0/lib/liquid/standardfilters.rb:36:in `escapeHTML': no implicit conversion of Fixnum into Strin
g (TypeError)
```

As you are using `escape` in titles: `<title>{% if page.title %}{{ page.title | escape }}{% else %}{{ site.title | escape }}{% endif %}</title>`   and many titles has only numbers, then it will fail.

A quick hack to fix it is to convert them to strings before using the `escape` filter, using the `capture` variable tag:

> Captures the string inside of the opening and closing tags and assigns
>   it to a variable. Variables that you create using capture are stored
>   as strings.

In `_includes/head.html`:

```
{% capture mytitle%}{{page.title}}{%endcapture%}
<title>{% if mytitle %}{{ mytitle | escape }}{% else %}{{ site.title | escape }}{% endif %}</title>
```

Comment: Thanks. This was very helpful, allowing me to locate and understand the problem; unfortunately, the solution didn't work, but I did find another way of doing things that seems to work. Hopefully it doesn't introduce new problems? I just replaced "escape" with "[escape_once](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/escape_once/)" in the original code.

Comment: @Kerim what was the error? I've tested the above solution locally and works fine.

Comment: It was the same error as before. Strange. I don't know why. Is there any reason not to use the "escape_once" version? It seems to be working...

Comment: lf you use the above two lines instead of the original title (the second line uses the newly created variable defined before) I'm pretty sure it should work. Anyway, using `escape_once` seems to be a better solution as it is cleaner and seems to handle numeric titles also.