# Jekyll Liquid Error, no implicit conversion of Integer to String. Zero information given and breaks when posts are generated

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have an issue with the website that i'm pushing to github pages.

My Gemfile has the github-pages gem and the jekyll gem has been commented out.

The error doesn't give any information as to where the error ocurrs expet for a file path (/_layout/defaults.html), which does not exist in my project. Building does not work and serving the website doesnt work. If someone could point me in a direction as to where I can find more info or has had this problem before that would be awesome!

```
---
title: "New Website, First Post"
layout: post
date: '2019-10-08'
categories: hyperlisk first
---

Hello World! This is my first ever jekyll post on my website. This is a new experiece and I would like to thank Evan Pratten (@ewpratten) for creating most of this website for me.
Go to his <a href="https://retrylife.ca">website</a>, he has some cool stuff over there! This blog will contain cool things I discover, tutorials and possible some updates to bigger projects I am working on. One such project called HyperEngine. That will be explained in a later post. The post directly following it will be a giant post about linear algebra and something called Optimal Control Theory.
```

^^
That is the only post and the error happens right after generating feed for posts
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to add a `default` layout; it sounds like some other file in your config is asking for it. The error message you're getting suggests that this layout template is referenced elsewhere in your code. (If you can share a pointer to your repo, it'll help answer your question more specifically!)

**In particular, unless you're doing something funky with your config, Jekyll tends to expect that you have a `_default.html` layout.** See the jekyll docs [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/04-layouts/#creating-a-layout).

You can add a minimal layout like so (taken from the page linked above):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ page.title }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ content }}
  </body>
</html>
```

This error is usually a sign that you are trying to cast some value to another (incompatible) type. For example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757708/no-implicit-conversion-of-integer-into-string-error-with-jekyll-posts-that-hav?rq=1), where a user ran into a similar error when trying to convert integers to a an escaped string.

(I'd also recommend cloning an existing jekyll website so that you can be sure you have a working installation.)